# Updating Output

Tags: c

I need to create an utility that "updates" its output, much like curl which keeps changing its last line:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8434  100  8434    0     0   4064      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  7695
```

I think using something like curses is not the way to go here. I don't want to manipulate the window, I want to simply change my last line of output.

The solution I have in mind is to print a number of backspaces enough to rewrite the line. But I haven't tested this yet. I'd like to know if this is a "correct" way of doing it, or if there is a better one.

Also, in my case I need to update the last line. So I don't need a so large number of backspaces (if that's the solution); however (to make it generic) if I need to update the -10 line, rewriting the same thing from -9th line on might not be that efficient (or maybe it is...).

Comment: well, nice syntax coloring for curl!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can backspace over the line, or (generally easier) print a carriage return, and just re-print the entire line. When you do, be sure to rewrite the *whole* line though -- if (for example) you have a number counting down to 0, when it drops from 100 to 99 (for example) it won't necessarily overwrite the '1' unless you assure that a space gets printed there.

Comment: I should have said that I'm on a FreeBSD-Mac, and this is intent to work on Unix-like systems, but thanks anyway. Thanks also for the tip on numbers, I see the formatting has to be fixed.

Comment: @sidyll: This should work just fine with FreeBSD-MAC and other Unix-like systems.

Comment: Yes it works! What a surprise for me, I thought the carriage return would be ignored. That's probably because I always see pairs of carriage returns and line feeds, so the effect in my system is similar to line feeds only. But `echo a^Mb` in bash echoes `b`. Fantastic. Please ignore my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

In DOS, you can simply print the carriage return without the line feed and overwrite the last line.